# ag-grid infinite scrolling bring all the data in loading

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am trying to use ag-grid with angular 
and get the ability of infinite scrolling get the data in scrolling 
but instead I get all the data in one time 
one I put my code in Plunkr instead the example of the ag-grid about this
and it is working well
what is the difference in my site and the plunkr site?

**This is my code:**

```
onGridReady(params) {
this.gridApi = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

var data = [];
let self = this;

var dataSource = {
  rowCount: null,
  getRows: function (params) {
    if (params.startRow == 0)
      data = [];
    console.log("asking for " + params.startRow + " to " + params.endRow);
    self.studentService.getStudents(params.startRow,params.endRow- params.startRow)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        data = data.concat(res);
        this.infiniteInitialRowCount=params.endRow+1;
        var rowsThisBlock = data.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
        var lastRow = -1;
        alert("row!");
        if (data.length < params.endRow) {
          lastRow = data.length;
          this.infiniteInitialRowCount=data.length;
        }
        params.successCallback(rowsThisBlock, lastRow);
      });
  }
 };
 params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
}
```